# Understanding issue in Scilab for my code

Tags: while-loop, scilab

I am doing a projectile motion where i need to plot curves between position x and y for various angles but the scilab shows only one plot. I am confused.
My code below

```
function[H,R,T]=projectile(m,r,h,c,rho,theta,v0,x0,y0,t0)

  g=9.8
  A=%pi*r^2
  k=c*rho*A/2;
  i=1
  t(i)=t0
  x(i)=x0
  y(i)=y0

  for j=0:5
    thetha=theta+j*15;
    vx(i)=v0*cos(thetha*%pi/180);
    vy(i)=v0*sin(thetha*%pi/180);
    while (y(i)>=0)
      v=sqrt(vx(i)^2+vy(i)^2);
      t(i+1)=t(i)+h;
      vx(i+1)=vx(i)-h*(k*v*vx(i)/m);
      vy(i+1)=vy(i)-h*(g+k*v*vy(i)/m);  
      x(i+1)=x(i)+h*vx(i)
      y(i+1)=y(i)+h*vy(i)
      i=i+1;  
    end
    plot(x(i),y(i),'.'); 
  end

  n=i-1
  R=x(n)-x(1);
  T=t(n);
  H=max(y)

endfunction
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the best theta, i.e. the one that maximizes the distance before y<0 ? Can you give typical values of m,r,h,c,rho,theta,v0,x0,y0,t0 to test your code ?

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet mass=0.005,r=0.01 h=0.25 c=0.46 rho=1.293 or 0 thetha=say 30 to 60 degree v0=49 x0=0 y0=0 t0=0. Actually i used for loop such that in thetha part so that for various angle i get the curves and corresponding values too but i am not getting different curves for different value of thetha

Comment: @StéphaneMottelet i just wanted to know the value in scilab console by giving the values actually for which particular value of thetha when i used your code is giving to me? Also i am not so familiar with the syntax you used so if possible if you can elaborate each step.

Answer (score 3):

You should use vectors to improve compacity and readability of your code. Here is my proposition of improved (and working) code:

```
function [H,R,T] = projectile(m,r,h,c,rho,theta0,v0,x0,y0,t0)
    g = 9.81
    A = %pi*r^2
    k = c*rho*A/2;

    for theta = theta0 + (0:15:75)
        v = v0*[cos(theta*%pi/180); sin(theta*%pi/180)];
        t = t0
        xy = [x0;y0]
        i = 1
        while xy(2,i) >= 0
            t(i+1) = t(i)+h;
            v = v + h*([0;-g] - k*norm(v)*v/m);
            xy(:,i+1) = xy(:,i) + h*v;
            i = i+1;
        end
        plot(xy(1,:), xy(2,:));
    end    

    R = xy(1,$) - xy(1,1);
    T = t($);
    H = max(xy(2,:))
endfunction

clf
[H,R,T] = projectile(1,0.1,0.001,2,1000,5,1,0,0,0)
```

[image: Screenshot of graphical output of program]

Comment: I'm thinking if you could further vectorize by using masking, like I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59760641/4999991).